# Structure as output of MATLAB Function Block through Simulink.Bus object

Tags: matlab, structure, simulink, bus, matlab-coder

I have a `MATLAB Function Block` where I compute X variables that I want to use later in a script.

My first option was to use `To Workspace` blocks for each of them, but since I have X variables, it fills up the model with blocks. The problem is that these X variables have different dimensions, otherwise I could just build a matrix.

My idea was to build a structure within the `MATLAB Function Block` and then use a single `To Workspace` block, but my research told me I would need a `Simulink.Bus` object to do so.

Is this approach at all the best way to achieve my goal? Thanks in advance for your input!

Comment: I think you need to specify size of fields at one instance of time. Your history is saved by the To Workspace block. I assume individual sizes do not change from one time step to next.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, defining the dimensions solved that part and the `To Workspace` did the rest. Now the question is if this is actually the best approach to my initial problem, so I'll edit the question.

Comment: If you are concerned only about simulation you could also send your data to an "extrinsic" function, accumulate it there and save it. I think using bus is better.